# what is the identity principle for meromorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F(z)$ and $F(z,\theta)$ be complex function with $z \in \mathbb{C^+} \equiv\{z \in \mathbb{C}: Im(z)>0\}$ $,\theta \in \mathbb{C} $ . Suppose that for $\theta \in \mathbb{R} $ we have $F(z)=F(z,\theta)$.

Now suppose that for $\Omega^+\equiv\Omega \cap \mathbb{C^+}\neq \varnothing,F(z,\theta),\Omega^-\equiv\Omega \cap \mathbb{C^-}\neq \varnothing$ can be  meromorphically continued in $z$ from $\Omega^+$ to $\Omega^-_\epsilon \subset \overline{ \Omega^-}$ ,where $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$.

To proof that there exist a meromorphic continuation form $\Omega^+$ into $\Omega^-_\epsilon \subset \overline{ \Omega^-},$ textbook says that the identity
principle for meromorphic functions  says that there exists a function,
meromorphic on $\Omega$ which equals to  $F(z)$ on $ \Omega^+$ and this function provide the continuation.

My question is what is the identity
principle for meromorphic functions?

Comment: I don't understand your question because of the horrible naming, the identity principle is that if a meromorphic function vanishes somewhere (on a small disk) then it vanishes everywhere. Then the only difficulty is to distinguish between the clockwide and the counterclockwise analytic continuation of $\log z$, the two are different because it has a branch point at $0$.

Comment: the identity principle for meromorphic functions it is cited here https://books.google.lu/books?id=GhAGCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA169&dq=%22identity+principle+for+meromorphic+functions%22+Introduction+to+Spectral+Theory+With+Applications+to+Schrodinger+Operators&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBsYSul97mAhWN5KQKHf_tAZsQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22identity%20principle%20for%20meromorphic%20functions%22%20Introduction%20to%20Spectral%20Theory%20With%20Applications%20to%20Schrodinger%20Operators&f=false

Comment: The identity principle more generally says that a function determined on a space with an accumulation point has a unique continuation

Comment: Could you give me a reference where it is proved?

Comment: I presume any book on complex analysis? Are you studying this for a class?

Comment: no . just trying to proof this theorem  https://books.google.lu/books?id=GhAGCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA169&dq=%22identity+principle+for+meromorphic+functions%22+Introduction+to+Spectral+Theory+With+Applications+to+Schrodinger+Operators&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBsYSul97mAhWN5KQKHf_tAZsQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22identity%20principle%20for%20meromorphic%20functions%22%20Introduction%20to%20Spectral%20Theory%20With%20Applications%20to%20Schrodinger%20Operators&f=false

Comment: I can't even understand the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

**The Identity Theorem for meromorphic Functions** says that in region $\Omega$ the following statements about the meromorphic Functions $f,g$ are equivalent :

1. $f=g$
2. The set $\{w \in \Omega \setminus (P(f) \cup P(g)) : f (w) = g(w)\}$ has a cluster point in $\Omega \setminus (P(f) \cup P(g))$
3. There is a point $c \in \Omega \setminus (P(f) \cup P(g))$ such $f^{(n)}(c)=g^{(n)}(c)$ for each non-negative integer $n$

where $P(.)$ is the pole set.